# Azure functions node error when doing npm start

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I am trying to run my azure functions locally by doing npm start or even the simple func start.

It was working perfectly until today when the following error started coming:

The func.deps.json file is here: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools and it has the dependency below.

I don't even use this and don't know what it is "Error: An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (func.deps.json) was not found: package: 'Marklio.Metadata', version: '1.2.20-beta' path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/Marklio.Metadata.dll' npm "

```
xxx-api@0.0.1 build:docs C:\Code\xxxx-api
> tsc --sourcemap --lib es2017 src/_doc/index.ts --outDir doc && node doc/index.js
```

Error:

```
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (func.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Marklio.Metadata', version: '1.2.20-beta'
    path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/Marklio.Metadata.dll'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2147516556
npm ERR! xxxx-api@0.0.1 install:extensions: `npm run build && cross-var func extensions install --prefix 
$npm_package_config_azureFunctions_outDir`
npm ERR! Exit status 2147516556
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the xxx-api@0.0.1 install:extensions script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-13T04_37_33_194Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2147516556
npm ERR! panthera-api@0.0.1 install:extensions: `npm run build && cross-var func extensions install --prefix 
$npm_package_config_azureFunctions_outDir`
npm ERR! Exit status 2147516556
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the xx-api@0.0.1 install:extensions script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-13T04_37_33_194Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2147516556
npm ERR! xx-api@0.0.1 prestart: `npm run install:extensions`
npm ERR! Exit status 2147516556
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the xxx-api@0.0.1 prestart script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-13T04_37_33_241Z-debug.log
```

My package.json file scripts are as follows:

```
    "scripts": {
        "build": "npm run clean && tsc && npm run build:configFiles && npm run build:docs",
        "build:production": "npm run prestart && cross-var rimraf $npm_package_config_azureFunctions_outDir/local.*.json && cross-var copyfiles package.json $npm_package_config_azureFunctions_outDir && cd dist && npm install --production",
        "build:configFiles": "cross-var copyfiles -u 1 \"$npm_package_config_azureFunctions_rootDir/**/*.json\" $npm_package_config_azureFunctions_outDir",
        "build:docs": "tsc --sourcemap --lib es2017 src/_doc/index.ts --outDir doc && node doc/index.js",
        "prestart": "npm run install:extensions",
        "start": "npm-run-all -p start:host watch watch:config",
        "start:doc": "npm run install:extensions && npm run start:host",
        "start:host": "cross-var func host start --prefix $npm_package_config_azureFunctions_outDir",
        "watch": "tsc --w",
        "watch:config": "cross-var onchange \"$npm_package_config_azureFunctions_rootDir/**/*.json\" -- npm run build:configFiles",
        "clean": "cross-var rimraf $npm_package_config_azureFunctions_outDir",
        "install:extensions": "npm run build && cross-var func extensions install --prefix $npm_package_config_azureFunctions_outDir",
        "install:extensions:force": "npm run build && cross-var func extensions install --prefix $npm_package_config_azureFunctions_outDir --force",
        "test": "jest",
        "precommit-msg": "echo 'Pre-commit checks...' && exit 0",
        "fix": "eslint --ext .ts --fix ",
        "fix-dry-run": "eslint --ext .ts --fix-dry-run",
        "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts"
    },
```

Finally, the contents of the log file mentioned above:

```
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'install:extensions'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v12.18.1
4 verbose run-script [
4 verbose run-script   'preinstall:extensions',
4 verbose run-script   'install:extensions',
4 verbose run-script   'postinstall:extensions'
4 verbose run-script ]
5 info lifecycle xxx-api@0.0.1~preinstall:extensions: xxx-api@0.0.1
6 info lifecycle xxx-api@0.0.1~install:extensions: xxx-api@0.0.1
7 verbose lifecycle xxx-api@0.0.1~install:extensions: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle xxx-api@0.0.1~install:extensions: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Code\xxxAPI\xxx-api\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Code\xxxAPI\xxx-api\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\xxx Sharma.STATEMERCANTILE\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Seq\;C:\Program Files\Seq\Client\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Users\xxx Sharma.STATEMERCANTILE\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\xxx Sharma.STATEMERCANTILE\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\xxx Sharma.STATEMERCANTILE\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\xxx Sharma.STATEMERCANTILE\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;
9 verbose lifecycle xxx-api@0.0.1~install:extensions: CWD: C:\Code\xxxAPI\xxx-api
10 silly lifecycle xxx-api@0.0.1~install:extensions: Args: [
10 silly lifecycle   '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'npm run build && cross-var func extensions install --prefix $npm_package_config_azureFunctions_outDir'
10 silly lifecycle ]
11 silly lifecycle xxx-api@0.0.1~install:extensions: Returned: code: 2147516556  signal: null
12 info lifecycle xxx-api@0.0.1~install:extensions: Failed to exec install:extensions script
13 verbose stack Error: xxx-api@0.0.1 install:extensions: `npm run build && cross-var func extensions install --prefix $npm_package_config_azureFunctions_outDir`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2147516556
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid xxx-api@0.0.1
15 verbose cwd C:\Code\xxxAPI\xxx-api
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "install:extensions"
18 verbose node v12.18.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.5
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2147516556
22 error xxx-api@0.0.1 install:extensions: `npm run build && cross-var func extensions install --prefix $npm_package_config_azureFunctions_outDir`
22 error Exit status 2147516556
23 error Failed at the xxx-api@0.0.1 install:extensions script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2147516556, true ]
```

Comment: Even when I do a simple func start I get this: Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (func.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Marklio.Metadata', version: '1.2.20-beta'
    path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/Marklio.Metadata.dll'

Answer (score 2):

Remove all references of this Marklio dependency from the `func.deps.json` and run this: `npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@3 --unsafe-perm true`

Comment: In my case I also needed to install `npm i --save-dev @types/node`

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you go to the path specified after the error message, and delete the Releases folder and run Visual Studio, it will redownload everything you need and it will run fine.